# Avoid exponent in float data

Tags: google-bigquery

Currently, `abc` is a float data type. I want to avoid exponent in float data. I have used the following to keep the data without an exponent, but it converts the data type as a string. I want to keep it as a float.

Can you please assist?

```
SELECT FORMAT('%.2f', abc) AS deduction FROM table
```

Comment: Could you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, you can SAFE_CAST to [NUMERIC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#cast_numeric)  as numeric values can contain fractional components with  exact precise values but [FLOAT64](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#cast_as_floating_point)  is an approximate numeric data type which gives approximate values with decimal or fractional components.

> Float and float-related SQL numeric data types hold approximate numeric values. They consist of a significant (a signed numeric value) and an exponent (a signed integer that specifies the magnitude of the significant).

Since NUMERIC values are exact precise values, you can try the below code to convert float value to numeric to avoid exponents. And if you have a bigger number then you can use [BIGNUMERIC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#cast_bignumeric) instead of NUMERIC.

```
SELECT SAFE_CAST(FORMAT('%.2f', abc) AS NUMERIC) AS deduction FROM table
```

Comment: But still, it gives me exponent. I want without exponent

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a casting operation to your FORMAT, so that the end result is casted to float:

```
SELECT CAST(FORMAT('%.2f', abc) AS float64) AS deduction FROM table
```

For more information on casting rules, you can visit the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules#comparison_chart)